# Highcharts yaxis labels Format

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels

Is there any way to format yaxis into something I want.

In fact, sometimes on the yaxis the data is shown with (k) on the right instead of thousand.

I want to remove (k). How can I do it?

The image of yaxis I want:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use formatter (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) and numberFormat() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat()

http://jsfiddle.net/K2X3Y/

```
 yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,0);
            }
        }
    },
```